# Hidden Key Bindings? (Specifically Ctrl+Alt+D and Shift+Super+!)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

I'm trying out Gnome on the newest version of Ubuntu and it seems that there are 'secret' key bindings. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> minimizes all my windows and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> Opens the first program in my dock. Under the settings and gconf-editor I cannot find these keybindings. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> also minimizes my windows but it shows that in the settings. Where can I find and edit all my key bindings? Specifically, how can I change the two key bindings previously mentioned? Thank you.

Comment: What was the "newest version of Ubuntu" at the time of asking this? Could you please add a version label to the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is some mystery, but it may be revealed:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is defined 
  in `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/show-desktop` (check in `dconf-editor`):

  [image: dconf-editor]

  but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is named `<Primary>` here. So we can find them in `gsettings`:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively | egrep "Primary.*Alt.*d"
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Primary><Super>d', '<Primary><Alt>d', '<Super>d']
  ```
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>!</kbd> (or more precise <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>)

  seems to be secret - are shown in `dconf-editor` and in `gsettings`:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively  | grep -i shift.*super
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-10 ['<Shift><Super>0']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-1 ['<Shift><Super>1']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-2 ['<Shift><Super>2']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-3 ['<Shift><Super>3']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-4 ['<Shift><Super>4']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-5 ['<Shift><Super>5']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-6 ['<Shift><Super>6']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-7 ['<Shift><Super>7']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-8 ['<Shift><Super>8']
  org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-shift-hotkey-9 ['<Shift><Super>9']
  ```
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

  is defined in GNOME Control Center → Keyboard (`gnome-control-center keyboard`) and in `dconf-editor` (see above):

  [image: Ctrl+Super+D]

  and in `gsettings`:

  ```
  gsettings list-recursively | egrep "Primary.*Super.*d"
  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Primary><Super>d', '<Primary><Alt>d', '<Super>d']
  ```

**Conclusion:**

1. all stuff is shown in `gsettings`. But `<Ctrl>` is named `<Primary>`.
2. all this stuff looks more and more like `RegEdit` in some other operating system.